# switch env inside a task

Tags: django, fabric

i like to update my local db with the server db. so i created a fabfile with 3 env. in my task first i go to server, do stuff there - then i like to switch e.g. to local and do stuff there. how can i change the environment inside a task?

for other stuff i used it like this: `fab www task` but then i have just the www env.

here is my fabfile.py:

```
def www():
    env.hosts  = ['s7.wservices.ch']
    env.user   = 'beautyparlour'
    env.dbname = 'db1'
    env.dbuser = 'user1'
    env.dbpass = 'password'

    env.name_vitualenv = 'django15' #name of the virtualenv
    env.name_folder   = 'projektfoldername' # name of the project folder


def dev():
    env.hosts  = ['s7.wservices.ch']
    env.user   = 'beautyparlour'
    env.dbname = 'db1'
    env.dbuser = 'user1'
    env.dbpass = 'password'

    env.name_vitualenv = 'django15' #name of the virtualenv
    env.name_folder   = 'projektfoldername' # name of the project folder



def home():
    env.hosts = ['localhost']
    env.user = ''
    env.dbname = 'dbx'
    env.dbuser = 'Roland'
    env.dbpass = ''

    env.name_vitualenv = 'django15' #name of the virtualenv
    env.name_folder   = 'projektfoldername' # name of the project folder



def update_db():
    '''
    use this on your local maschine to get the db from the live system
    fab update_db

    1. create a backup on server
    2. download the backup
    3. unzip the packup media and sql
    4. load the sql dump to database

    '''

    # switch env to server ??
    www()

    ...do stuff on server

    # switch env to local ??
    home()

    ... do stuff local
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the perfect thing to use for [roles](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.0/api/core/decorators.html) and [settings](http://fabric.readthedocs.org/en/1.4.3/api/core/context_managers.html)

First you should probably split up your commands a bit better, and then create some role definitions. If you want to use a specific environment then it is probably best to use `settings`

```
from fabric.api import roles, settings, task

env.roledefs = {
    "www": ["some_remote_server"],
    "other": ["wherever"],
}

@roles("www")
@task
def do_stuff_on_www():
    with settings(user="myname", some_prop="bar"):
        # Do some stuff on the www server
```

Given that you are using a context manager your environment will reset to the default that you originally entered once the function finishes.

By the way you dont have to specify any new host definitions to run a command on localhost. You can just run the fabric method `local` and that will handle all calls on your local box. `local` is a convenience wrapper of subprocess module, so theres no fabric/paramiko magic going on in the background. The code can be found [here](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/blob/master/fabric/operations.py) if you're interested in looking

Comment: thanks, this looks fine to me but if i do it this way how can i set e.g. `env.user`, `env.dbname`, `env.name_folder`, ... for each environment?

Comment: the same way you did it before? you can also just create a new function `load_env` that scans for which role you are using and then loads the user, dbname, and name_folder appropriately.

Comment: Actually probably just better to use the `settings` context manager. I updated the answer to reflect this

Comment: i see, thats a way of course. my idea was to have two files in the end. file1: defining the envs (like a settings file). file2: tasks and functions. so then i can use the same two files for each project and just have to update file1.

im still not sure whats the best solution.

Comment: So the problem with your original method is that you always need to declare which settings your task needs to have at the beginning of your function call, otherwise the settings from another task will bleed over into your new task, potentially creating bugs. The cool thing about the context manager is, you can have default settings, but then override them when need be, and when you are not inside the manager then your settings will revert to default